# Nonvanishing vectorfield on $S^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, vector-fields

> Let $\tau: S^n \to S^n, x \mapsto -x$ be the antipodal map. Show, that
>   these are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\tau$ is (smooth) homotopic to the identity map $\text{id}$ on $S^n$
> 2. $n$ is odd
> 3. There is a nonvanishing smooth vector field on $S^n$

I want to show $(1 \implies 2)$, $(2 \implies 3)$ and $(3 \implies 1)$, but I am struggling with the last two.

**Attempt**:
$(1 \implies 2)$: I'd suggest embedding the sphere into euclidian space and take a canonical volume form. Let $\tau$ and $\text{id}$ be homotopic and $\omega_p(v_1, ..., v_n) = \det(p, v_1, ..., v_n)$ a volume form for all $p \in S^n \subseteq \mathbb R^{n+1}$. Since volume forms are nonzero, the integral neither is. For homotopic maps, the integral of the pullbacks are equal, thus we get
$$0 \neq \int_{S^n} \omega = \int_{S^n} \text{id}^* \omega = \int_{S^n} \tau^* \omega = (-1)^{n+1} \int_{S^n} \omega,$$
which can only be true for $n$ being odd. I think this should be fine.

$(2 \implies 3)$: Obviously, we have to construct a vector field on $S^{2m+1}$ for $m \in \mathbb N_0$. I think on the 1-sphere a rotation by $\pi$ would be such a vector field, so maybe in polar coordinates something like $\vartheta \mapsto \vartheta + \pi$ for $\vartheta \in [0, 2\pi)$. Can one generalize this for higher dimensions and if so, how? If I rotate the 3-sphere by $\pi$, how would I explicitly define the map? Embedding it into euclidian space seems so complicated here.

$(3 \implies 1)$: Let $X$ be a smooth nonvanishing vector field. We have to build a homotopy $F: [0, 1] \times S^n \to S^n$. I first thought of something like
$$F(t, p) = \cos(\pi t) \cdot p,$$
but it didn't use the property of $X$ and leaves the sphere (e.g. $F(1/2, p) = 0$), so it is obviously wrong. My professor gave the hint to assume that $X(p)$ is orthogonal to $p$, but why would that be allowed?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (2) implies (3), take the unit sphere in complex Euclidean space, and rotate by multiplying by unit complex numbers. In other words, the vector field is $X(z)=iz$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}^k$, with $|z|=1$. This is the sphere $S^n$ where $n=2k-1$.

For (3) implies (1), take you vector field $X$, let $Y=X/|X|$, and flow along $Y$ for time $\pi$.

Comment: how do you identify $\mathbb {C} ^k$ and $\mathbb {R} ^{2k-1}$?

Comment: @S.R: The sphere is $S^n=S^{2k-1}$, sitting as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{2k}=\mathbb{C}^k$.